# How to autologin to oracle using OCI with C++ using windows credentials?

Tags: c++, oracle, single-sign-on, oracle-call-interface

Basically I have a C++ app which login to oracle db using OCI.
DB is configured to authenticate users from windows domain user accounts.

At the moment when my client log in, I pass user name and password to OCI in order to login by setting OCI_ATTR_PASSWORD and OCI_ATTR_USERNAME attributes in user session handle.

What should I do in the code to make OCI take windows credencials directly instead of me providing them through the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Oracle Call Interface Programmer's Guide - OCISessionBegin()](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96584/oci15r13.htm)

> The second type of credentials
>   supported are external credentials. No
>   attributes need to be set on the user
>   session handle before calling
>   OCISessionBegin(). The credential type
>   is OCI_CRED_EXT. This is equivalent to
>   the Oracle7 'connect /' syntax. If
>   values have been set for
>   OCI_ATTR_USERNAME and
>   OCI_ATTR_PASSWORD, then these are
>   ignored if OCI_CRED_EXT is used.